# Soap update error Sharepointapi.php

Tags: php, sharepoint, soap

Using sharepointapi.php in order to update some value into a sharepoint list. I get the next request XML, generated by sharepointapi.php:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <listName>CONTRACTS</listName>
    <updates>
      <Batch ListVersion="1" OnError="Continue">
      <Method Cmd="Update" ID="1">
        <Field Name="state">Awaiting F</Field>
                 <Field Name="ID">10</Field>
               </Method>
      </Batch>
      </updates>
    </UpdateListItems>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And I got this from the server:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body><soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring>
    <detail>
      <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">Cannot access a closed Stream.
      </errorstring>
    </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note. I am actually able to get all the rows from the list.

Is my query bad formatted?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your trying to update the ID of a listitem. The ID is generated by SharePoint and cannot be changed.

Comment: so, how is the proper format to achieve the update operation over item ID=10

Comment: The <Field Name="ID">10</Field> is constructed in that way by the library. Do you think is a error?